# How to handle quoted arguments in $@?

Tags: bash

For example here is `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "${@}"; do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

If you run `./test.sh one 'two' "three"`, you will get

```
one
two
three
```

But what I want to get is:

```
one
'two'
"three"
```

How can I get this?

Thanks.

Comment: `./test.sh one "'two'" '"three"'` :P Just to inform you, the problem is not in your script. bash calling this script would strip out the quotes...

Comment: Thanks for the info. But a user(of the script) usually don't know to do that. So there is no way to pass quoted arguments transparently in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Bash strips the quotes from strings. Thus if you want quotes, you need to put them inside other quotes.

Doing:

```
./test.sh one "'two'" '"three"'
```

should give you the result you want.

Another possibility is to escape your quotes so that bash knows that it is part of the string:

```
./test.sh one \'two\' \"three\"
```

will work, so will:

```
./test.sh "one" "\'two\'" "\"three\""
```

Otherwise you can always add the quotes again in your script by doing:

```
echo "\"${i}\""
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

you need to adapt your input. For example like this:

```
# ./test.sh one \'two\' \"three\"
one
'two'
"three"
#
```